# How do I get the value of a sibling class (.priceToCalc) and set the value of another class (.totalAmt) after a click on a sibling

Tags: jquery, razor, event-handling, siblings

How do I get the value of a sibling class (.priceToCalc) and set the value of the class (.totalAmt) after the users enters a value into the (.numItems) input.

```
<table>
    <tr id="mainRow">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDesc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HasPicture)
        </td>
        <td id="tdNumItems">
            <form asp-controller="Index" name="Quantity">
                <p>
                    Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" size="3" id="number-@(item.itemKey)" class="numItems">
                </p>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td id="uprice-@(item.itemKey)" class="priceToCalc" data-topass="@item.UnitPrice" >
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            <form  asp-controller="Index" name="Amount">
                <p id="price">
                    Amount: <input type="text" name="Amount" size="5" disabled="disabled" id="amt-@(item.itemKey)" class="totalAmt">
                </p>  
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.numItems').mouseleave(function () {
        var numberVal = $(this).val();
        var idOfAmt = $(event.target).attr('id');
        var valueTomult=($("#tdNumItems").siblings('.priceToCalc').text());
        idOfAmt = idOfAmt.split('-');
        var idOfPrice; //value of next sibling,don't know this either
        alert(idOfAmt[1] + '- val>' + numberVal + '-amt>' + valueTomult);

    });
});
```

It only returns the value of the first loop of selector .priceToCalc.

Comment: You need to be careful when using classes, as they can return more than one result if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly doing this on `mouseleave` is a little odd. It would be better for the user to see the calculation change as they type, which you can achieve using `keyup`.

To actually do what you require you can use DOM traversal to find the `tr` nearest the `input` which raised the event, then `find()` to retrieve the required child elements to base the calculation on. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.numItems').keyup(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var unitPrice = parseFloat($row.find('.priceToCalc').text());
        $row.find('.totalAmt').val(this.value * unitPrice);
    });
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldyhvn1z/)

Comment: Spot on mate. I am at the bumpy bottom of the learning curve with jquery and this has costs me far to many hours trying to sort it. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad to help